# how to setup webspeed in progress 4gl trial version

Tags: installation, openedge, progress-4gl, trial, webspeed

can someone tell me how can I setup webspeed on progress 4gl 60 days trial version for a practice purpose? I tried so much but found no way to set up in trial version. Any online environment anything in which I can practice?
Thanks in advance for your help and support guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current release of Progress, and thus the downloadable trial, is OpenEdge 12.  WebSpeed was retired in OpenEdge 11 and is, therefore, not available in the OpenEdge 12 trial.

Comment: PAS replaces webspeed aswell as the ”appserver” so thats the new approach to search out.